# Delete all data of sql server database in java application

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database

I want to delete all data from all tables in a SQL server database. I managed to collect all tables with the [getTables()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/gettables-method-sqlserverdatabasemetadata?view=sql-server-ver15) method but I do not know how to iterate through them or access them. I have written down the idea of my code: I thought I could just execute `TRUNCATE TABLE` for every table and then I should have all data deleted.

```
private void emptyMssqldb() throws TSTDBException, SQLException {

    Connection connMsSql = DBConnection.getConnectionToMsSql();

    ResultSet rs = DBConnection.getConnectionToMsSql().getMetaData().getTables(null, null, null, null);

    TSTDB.execute_sql(connMsSql, "TRUNCATE TABLE " + tablename );

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/retrieving-result-set-data-sample?view=sql-server-ver15 might help you understand how to use the ResultSet object. Did you research this at all? Does sound like an odd requirement for an application to want to delete all the data though.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` is likely not going to work, as you can't `TRUNCATE` a table that has any foreign keys (and I *assume* you do). This feels like an XY Problem though; why do you want to delete all the data?

Comment: @Larnu I have two databases with the same structure (one oracle and one SQL server) and I want to develop an application which migrates all data from the oracle to the SQL server db. Thats why I want to empty the database first.

Comment: Why is there data in there in the first place then? If you're starting from scratch, it would seem like a better idea to create the database from your source control; it'll be empty then. Certainly, as I suspected, `TRUNCATE` isn't going to work here due to your existing `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, so you'd have to `DELETE` everything; which'll be slow and you'd have to do so in the correct order. You're approaching this from the wrong direction.

Comment: It is a requirement (obstacle) which I got with this task that there are already data in the target database. Then I should delete everything, also the tables themselves or is there a way to just delete all data, foreign keys etc?

Comment: Then `DROP` everything and recreate from source control. Just "looping" a `TRUNCATE`/`DELETE` on every table will (very likely) fail the moment you get to tables which are referenced as foreign keys. Or you'd have to `DROP` all your foreign keys, `TRUNCATE` and recreate them; not really something you *want* to be doing from Java.

Comment: Ah okay I see, now I got it

Comment: This is why the "simplest" answer is just `DROP` (make sure you back it up first!) the database and recreate it; you won't suffer any integrity issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate scripts to create DB with out data. Right click on DB> Tasks > Generate Scripts. There you can select what you want to script (tables, sps, views, etc.) by default this option generates an empty database.